# Apache / PHP ReWrite Rules for Rest API

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to build an RestAPI without use of any 3party framework and would like to be able to allow the api be hit via

http://mywebserver.com/restAPI/player for example

currently it only works via

http://mywebserver.com/restAPI/index.php/player

my current .httpaccess looks like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

hope someone can tell me how to be able to achieve my goal

thanks

Comment: I wrote a little tutorial on how to do this: https://gist.github.com/odan/e791bb29e2a1eab4ac6f2be4bbf86e12

Comment: i have no issue with my routes but with the rewrite i changed my .httpaccess to yours and when i go to
http://192.168.1.209/restAPI/player/1234 i get
The requested URL /restAPI/player/1234 was not found on this server.
but http://192.168.1.209/restAPI/index.php/player/1234 works just fine